# How to change the year when using POSIX class with Lubridate functions?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I am trying to reassign the year but get an error for an invalid timezone for certain timezones when using POSIX classes.

When I run this code

```
x <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01", tz = "America/Costa_Rica")
year(x)
year(x) <-  1972
```

I get this error

```
Error in (function (dt, year, month, yday, mday, wday, hour, minute, second,  : 
  CCTZ: Invalid timezone of the input vector: "America/Costa_Rica"
```

But when I run it with `EST` or `UTC` it works

```
x <- as.POSIXct("2000-01-01", tz = "EST")
year(x)
year(x) <-  1972
x
```

I get the output

```
"1972-01-01 EST"
```

But the only two timezones I could get to work are EST and UTC. I randomly tried several other timezones from `OlsonNames()` and they all gave me CCTZ: Invalid timezone error. Some others that I tried were Indian/Mayotte, GMT, Etc/GMT-8.

I have made sure my Lubridate is updated and even downloaded the dev version just to try but it gave me the same errors.

Specifics: MacOS 10.15.7; R version 4.0.3; the only library I have loaded is Lubridate

Comment: This works for me, it appears to be a bug in R, perhaps in connection with the timezone settings in MacOS.

Comment: I was curious myself if it was a bug in base R, so I download an older version of R 3.3.3 and I do not get the error (though many warnings which is not surprising). What version of R are you using?

Comment: At work I use 3.6.4 on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a thread on GitHub that answers this https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/928

It appears to be an issue with R 4.0.3 and macOS Catalina. I was able to solve my problem by using R 4.0.2 instead.